# populating dropdown based in first selection

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

My COntroller

```
public function gettestRecieve() {
    $test = array('recieve' => $this->input->post('recieve'));
    $data = $this->test->getrecieve($test);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

My Model

```
function getAcademic($test) {
    $this->db->select('a_y');
    $this->db->where($test);
    $this->db->distinct();
    $result = $this->db->get('table');

    $return = array();
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
            $return[''] = 'select';
        foreach($result->result_array() as $row){
            $return[$row['a_y']] = $row['a_y'];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

My view

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#test').change(function () {
    var add = $(this).val();
    //console.log(add);
    $.ajax({   
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>getAcademic",
        method: "POST", 
        data: {testing: add},

        success: function(add) {
            var data = JSON.parse(add);//parse response to convert into onject
            console.log(data);//see your result in console
            //alert(data[0].Ayear); 
            $('#good').html('<option value="'+ Ayear +'" >'+ Ayear +'</option>');
        }
    })
});
```

});

this gives me an error object HTMLSelectElement what does it mean, when i tried to look at my console it gives me a right value {"": "A & Y", 2014-2015: "2014-2015"} but in frontend gives an error, how could i fix this! can someone know this error, thanks and advanced

Comment: where you are calling `getAcademic()` in your controller?

Comment: i set it up in routes but i forgot to change here. :)